# Swiper - prevent click on parent element when drag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

Is there a quick solution to prevent click at parent element when I release drag on slider?

Problem: click on the product card is counted when the user drags a photo in the slider. What way to make sure that a click on the product card is not counted when the user drags and releases a photo in the slider? [image]

```
<ProductCard onClick={onClick}>
  <div className={image_wrapper}>
    <ProductCardCarousel images={photos} />
  </div>
  <div>Product Name</div>
  ....
</div>
```

Perhaps there is a setting in the swiper, which I can'n find, or do I have to write it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.stopPropagation() method.
This method will prevent the parent event handlers from being executed.

Example -

```js
function onClick(e){
e.stopPropagation();
console.log("Click handler")
//code here
}
```

Comment: This will turn off all clicks, I need the clicks to stay on the card, but not register when ondragover in the slider